# GIT for teams - team seeing changes in branches without deploying to the app

Tags: git, plotly, devops, plotly-dash

We are a team of two devs. One is working from a Plotly Dash Enterprise workspace to push changes directly from master to a deployed app, the other from VisualStudio.

So far I could push changes to the deployed app directly.

We would like to work with branches so the changes I make do not go directly to the app but instead my teammate fetches all changes commited by me to the branch and he decides if merging it to the master and deploying or not.

Right now I have only been able to share changes in Branches with my teammate by doing:
**$ git push origin Branch**
which changes the app, even if it does not go to master.

How can we share the changes that happen in a branch without deploying? We also tried to fetch/pull after just commiting, but it didn't work.

Comment: If you don't want to deploy, just don't push to master. You can both checkout any branch and work on it by committing and pushing. As long as it's not master, there won't be any deploy from what I understand.

Comment: _We also tried to fetch/pull after just commiting, but it didn't work_ can you explain more what didn't work and which steps you followed?